# Converting nxm matrix into a 1xm cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell-array

How can I convert a 2xn matrix into a 1xn cell array, concatenating the values upwards so the cell array contains the column vectors of the original matrix?
I want to do this more efficiently than a simple for loop going through each column (as this is matlab and loops are inefficient)

Say I had a 2x2 matrix [1,2;3,4]. I wish to convert it into a cell array {[1,3],[2,4]}. I have looked up about mat2cell but can't see how to keep the length of the cell array while concatenating upwards.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of additional arguments to [mat2cell](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to format the output as you like.

In your case, specify that each cell contains 2 element in a row:

```
A = [1 2;3 4];
B = mat2cell(A.',[1 1]).';

celldisp(B)
```

`B` is now a `1x2` cell:

```
B{1} =

     1     3



B{2} =

     2     4
```

Comment: Thanks! But would this work for a general case, where there are any number of columns? eg A = [1 2 3;4 5 6]

Comment: You can make it general by using calls to `numel` and `size` as I did in my answer.  The `.'` notation is probably simpler to follow than my use of `permute`.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a dense line, but I think this does what you're after.

```
A=[1 2;3 4];
permute(mat2cell(reshape(permute(A,[2 1]),[numel(A) 1]),size(A,1)*ones(size(A,2),1),[1] ),[2 1])
```